# Synchronizations in observers that do not agree in simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

Suppose in special relativity we have two observers $A$ and $B$. Suppose that they agree with each  other in the proper time interval on each other worldlines   that is , if $t$ is the proper time of $A$ and $t'$ is proper time of $B$ for  two events $e_1$ and $e_2$ in the Worldline of $B$ we have $t_1-t_2=t'_1-t'_2$ analogously for $B$.

Suppose also that they do not agree in simultaneity, my question is  can we synchronizes their clocks?

Comment: What is meant by proper time of an observer. Proper time is for an event not for observer.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: For a start, you don't have to suppose that two observers will agree on a proper time interval. When you say 'they do not agree in simultaneity' what do you mean? When you say 'can we synchronise their clocks?' what do you mean? How can 'we' synchronise their clocks?

Answer (score 0):

According to Einstein we have

> Let a ray of light start at the "A time" $t_{\mathrm{A}}$ from A
> towards $\mathrm{B}$, let it at the "B time" $t_{\mathrm{B}}$ be
> reflected at $\mathrm{B}$ in the direction of $\mathrm{A}$, and arrive
> again at $\mathrm{A}$ at the "A time" $t_{\mathrm{A}}^{\prime}$. In
> accordance with definition the two clocks synchronize if
> $$ t_{\mathrm{B}}-t_{\mathrm{A}}=t_{\mathrm{A}}^{\prime}-t_{\mathrm{B}}
>  $$

Suppose $dt_A=dt_B$ and suppose an event $e_B$ in the worldline of $B$ at  $t_B=0$ is simultaneous  with an $e_A$ event at $t_A=5$. Suppose also $A$ is at a distance $d$ from $B$. To synchronize their clocks $A$ sends light toward $B$ at his time  $t_A=t_0$ and at $t_A=t_0+\frac{d}{c}$ he set his clock to zero. When light arrives at $B$ immediately the clock of $B$ is set to zero.
Now according to $A$ the  $t_A=0$ and $t_B=0$,but according to $t_B=0$ is simultaneous with $t_A=-5$.

Now suppose that the procedure above has been done . Let us say that $A$ sends another light towards $B$ at $t_A=10$ since  they do not agree in simultaneity $B$ will say that light was send from $A$ at time another  $t_B=5$ and he will say that light arrives when his time was $t'_B=5+\frac{d}{c}$. The light will arrives at $A$ at time $t_A'=10+\frac{2d}{c}$

We have than that $t'_B-t_A=5+\frac{d}{c}-10=-5+\frac{d}{c}$ and $t_A'-t_B'=5+\frac{d}{c}$

Since  $t_A'-t_B'\neq=t_B'-t_A$ according to Einstein the clocks are not synchronized.